# Columns auto fit in openXML using .NET Core

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am able to generate an Excel file using OpenXML, but the column's width are not adjusting as per the sheet data.

Here is my code:

```
public static byte[] GetExcelFileStreamTemp<T>(SearchResults<T> result, PropertyInfo[] properties, string[] excludeColNames, string[] currencyColNames, string[] dateTimeColNames, string[] dateColNames,bool showMessage = false, string blacklist = "", Dictionary<string, string> renameHeaders = null)
{
    var list = result.Results as List<T>;

    using (MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(file, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            // Generate Workbook Part Content
            WorkbookPart workBookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
            workBookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workBookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

            // Set Workbook Styles
            WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart = workBookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
            workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = GenerateWorkbookStyles();
            workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();

            // Add a Sheets to the Workbook
            Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

            // Add a new sheet and link it to the worksheet
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
                    {
                        Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                        SheetId = 1,
                        Name = "Report"
                    };

            sheets.Append(sheet);

            // Add data to the worksheet
            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            if (result.Results != null)
            {
                AddHeaderRow(sheetData, properties, excludeColNames);
                AddDataRow(sheetData, list, properties, excludeColNames, currencyColNames, dateTimeColNames, dateColNames);

                // AutoFit all columns in the worksheet
                AutoFitAllColumns(worksheetPart);
            }

            // Save the changes
            workBookPart.Workbook.Save();

            // Show Disclaimer at the bottom of the excel file.
            if (showMessage)
            {
                var defaultWorkSheet = GetWorksheet(spreadsheetDocument, "Report");
                AddDisclaimer(defaultWorkSheet, (uint)(list?.Count ?? 0));
            }

            // Save the Spreadsheet Document
            spreadsheetDocument.Close();

            return file.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
        
private static void AddHeaderRow(SheetData sheetData, PropertyInfo[] properties, string[] excludeColNames, string blacklist = "", Dictionary<string, string> renameHeaders = null)
{
    var r = new Regex(@"
                            (?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z]) |
                            (?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z]) |
                            (?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    Row headerRow = new Row();

    // Generate Headers
    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
    {
         var displayName = GetAttributeDisplayName(properties[i]);
         var cellValue = string.Empty;

         if (renameHeaders != null && renameHeaders.ContainsKey(properties[i].Name.ToString()))
         {
             cellValue = r.Replace(Regex.Replace(renameHeaders[properties[i].Name.ToString()],
                                                   Regex.Escape(blacklist), string.Empty), " ");
         }
         else if (displayName == null)
         {
             //// Pass backlist as like -- "[@,\\.\";'\\\\]"
             cellValue = r.Replace(Regex.Replace(properties[i].Name,
                                                   Regex.Escape(blacklist), string.Empty), " ");
         }
         else
         {
             cellValue = displayName;
         }

         DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
         cell.StyleIndex = 2U; // third style , bold font with  borders
         cell.CellValue = new CellValue(cellValue);
         cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                
         // don't include columns that are in excludeColNames
         if (!excludeColNames.Contains(properties[i].Name))
         {
             headerRow.Append(cell);
         }
    }

    sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);
}
        
private static void AddDataRow<T>(SheetData sheetData, List<T> list, PropertyInfo[] properties, string[] excludeColNames, string[] currencyColNames, string[] dateTimeColNames, string[] dateColNames)
{
    // Get Details
    foreach (var t in list)
    {
        Row detailRow = new Row();

        foreach (var p in t.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            // don't include columns that are in excludeColNames
            if (!excludeColNames.Contains(p.Name))
            {
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.StyleIndex = 1U; // second style , normal font with borders
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(p.GetValue(t, null)?.ToString());
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;

                // Currency Columns
                if (currencyColNames.Contains(p.Name))
                {
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
                    cell.StyleIndex = 3U; // default number format.
                                                 
                    cell.CellValue = (p.GetValue(t, null) != null) ? new CellValue(Convert.ToDecimal(p.GetValue(t, null))) : new CellValue();
                }

                // Date Time Columns
                if (dateTimeColNames.Contains(p.Name))
                {
                    //cell.DataType = CellValues.Date;
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.StyleIndex = 4U; // default date format.
                                                  
                    cell.CellValue = (p.GetValue(t, null) != null) ? new CellValue(((DateTime)p.GetValue(t, null)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")) : new CellValue("");
                }

                // Date Only Columns
                if (dateColNames.Contains(p.Name))
                {
                    //cell.DataType = CellValues.Date;
                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                    cell.StyleIndex = 7U; // Short date format.
                                                  
                    cell.CellValue = (p.GetValue(t, null) != null) ? new CellValue(((DateTime)p.GetValue(t, null)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) : new CellValue("");
                }

                detailRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }
        }

        sheetData.AppendChild(detailRow);
    }
}
        
private static void AutoFitAllColumns(WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
{
    Columns columns = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<Columns>();

    if (columns == null)
    {
        columns = new Columns();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAt(columns, 0);
    }

    // Iterate over all columns and set BestFit to true
    foreach (Column column in columns.Elements<Column>())
    {
        column.BestFit = true;
    }
}
```

I used `column.BestFit = true;` for column width in `AutoFitAllColumns` method, but the column's width is not set based on the data.

Current output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBQv9.png)

Expected output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MASNE.png)